# Specflow test case deadlocks

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, specflow

I have written a test case in specflow as below:

```
[Given(@"I have removed entity")]
    public async Task GivenIHaveRemovedEntity(Table table)
    {
        var employee = table.CreateInstance<TableGeneralInfoDto>();
        var schemas = await DataCatalogHooks.SchemasController.Get();
        var schema = schemas.Value.First(x => x.Name != null &&
            x.Name.Equals("BATCH_TEST", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        var objectTypes = await DataCatalogHooks.ObjectTypesController.Get();
        var objectType = objectTypes.Value.First(x =>
            x.Name.Equals("Table", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        );
        employee.SchemaId = schema.Id;
        employee.SystemName = string.Concat(schema.Name, ".", employee.ObjectName);
        employee.ObjectTypeId = objectType.Id;
        _scenarioContext["employee"] = employee;
        try
        {
            var entity = await DataCatalogHooks.TablesController.Get(employee.SystemName);
            await DataCatalogHooks.TablesController.Delete(entity.Value.Id);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

TablesController.Delete() method calls as asynchronous method:

```
public async Task DeleteAsync(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var relations = new List<DomainModels.Relation>();
            relations.AddRange(_relationRepository.GetBySourceTableIdAsync(id).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
            relations.AddRange(_relationRepository.GetByReferenceTableIdAsync(id).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
            await _relationRepository.Delete(relations);
            await _client.DeleteAsync(id);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Validation.ExceptionManager.ThrowException(new Exception(e.Message));
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And this method internally calls http request as below :

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SwaggerResponse<EntityCollection>> GetEntityCollectionAsync(string idOrName, string tenantId, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
            var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/api/v1.0/{tenantId}/collections/{idOrName}");
            urlBuilder_.Replace("{idOrName}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ConvertToString(idOrName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
            urlBuilder_.Replace("{tenantId}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ConvertToString(tenantId, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

            var client_ = _httpClient;
            try
            {
                using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
                {
                    request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("GET");
                    request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

                    var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                    request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
              
                    var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    try
                    {
                        var headers_ = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                        if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                                headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                        }

                        var status_ = ((int)response_.StatusCode).ToString();
                        if (status_ == "200")
                        {
                                var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<EntityCollection>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                                return new SwaggerResponse<EntityCollection>((int)response_.StatusCode, headers_, objectResponse_.Object);
                            }
                        return new SwaggerResponse<EntityCollection>((int)response_.StatusCode, headers_, default(EntityCollection));
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (response_ != null)
                            response_.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
            }

    }
```

This method returns the result successfully(200). But after executing this method unit test continues spinning. No error or success result shows.
If I call the Delete API from swagger, it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if the test reaches the last `finally` block?

Comment: yes, test reaches both finally blocks and also reaches at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usages of .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); may, in some situations, deadlock the thread managing the sync context and through that the context itself.

I have removed GetAwaiter().GetResult() and made the method async. this solved the issue

Comment: I don't see calls to`GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in the code in your question. Can you add that code to your question? This is one of these obscure problems I google for and there is this one random guy on the internet that encountered it... and you are that guy. The addition of the "GetAwaiter()" code to your question would help give people some context.